# Notification bar with countdown timer

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, countdown

I am trying to build a responsive notification bar with bootstrap, however my media query are not behaving properly,

I have some text with  tag which I want to decrease size on smaller screen but only my timer text is changing size. also I want to add some margin between my text and button on smaller screen, but its not working.

Please look at my code and suggest some changes :|

```js
$(function() {
            var endDate = new Date();
            endDate = new Date(2016, 12 - 1, 31);
            $('#dcountdown').countdown({
      until: endDate
            });

            $('#dclose').click(function() {
                $(this).parent().slideUp();
            });
        });
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,700italic);
        @media only screen and (max-width: 700px){.dcontent strong{font-size: 50%;}.countdown-section{font-size: 80%;padding-bottom: 10%;} .mybutton{padding: 2px;}}

        #dbanner {
            position: top;
            bottom: 0px;
            height: auto;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: "Open Sans";
            text-shadow: 1px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        }
        
        .dcontent {
            padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        .dcontent strong {
            font-size: 20px;
            color: #fff;
            white-space: nowrap;
            margin-right: 30%;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #dclose {
            position: absolute;
            font-size: 8px;
            height: 20px;
            line-height: 10px;
            top: 5px;
            right: 10px;
            color: #fff;
        }

        #dclose:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .change-color {
            background-color: #000000;
            color: #FFF;
            text-align: center;

        }
        .mybutton{
            padding: 5px;
            background: #006622;
            background-size: 100%;
            border-radius: 0px;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .countdown-section {
            padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
            text-align: center;
            
            
        }

        .countdown-amount {
            padding: 0 5px 0 0;
        }

        .countdown-period {
            text-transform: none;
        }

        .countdown-descr {
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.js"></script>
<div id="dbanner" class="change-color">
      <div class="dcontent">
          <strong>Some Text Here Some Text Here Some </strong>  <span id="dcountdown"></span> <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" role="button" class="mybutton">Apply Now</a>
      </div>
      <div id="dclose">close me!</div>
    </div>
<script src="https://lizatom.com/wp-content/themes/lizatom2015/banner/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://lizatom.com/wp-content/themes/lizatom2015/banner/jquery.plugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Thank you

[Mobile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOKbr.jpg)

The previous issue has been fixed now, but on mobile view there is some white space on the right side, how do I fix that

[Mobile View new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD0wz.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move whole statement @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {... ...} down of your rules. Then it should work right.

```js
$(function() {
            var endDate = new Date();
            endDate = new Date(2016, 12 - 1, 31);
            $('#dcountdown').countdown({
      until: endDate
            });

            $('#dclose').click(function() {
                $(this).parent().slideUp();
            });
        });
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,700italic);
       #dbanner {
            position: top;
            bottom: 0px;
            height: auto;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: "Open Sans";
            text-shadow: 1px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        }
        
        .dcontent {
            padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        .dcontent strong {
            font-size: 20px;
            color: #fff;
            white-space: nowrap;
            margin-right: 30%;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #dclose {
            position: absolute;
            font-size: 8px;
            height: 20px;
            line-height: 10px;
            top: 5px;
            right: 10px;
            color: #fff;
        }

        #dclose:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .change-color {
            background-color: #000000;
            color: #FFF;
            text-align: center;

        }
        .mybutton{
            padding: 5px;
            background: #006622;
            background-size: 100%;
            border-radius: 0px;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .countdown-section {
            padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
            text-align: center;
            
            
        }

        .countdown-amount {
            padding: 0 5px 0 0;
        }

        .countdown-period {
            text-transform: none;
        }

        .countdown-descr {
        }
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
 .dcontent strong {
  font-size: 50%;
 }
 .countdown-section {
  font-size: 80%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
 }
 .mybutton {
  padding: 2px;
 }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.js"></script>
<div id="dbanner" class="change-color">
      <div class="dcontent">
          <strong>Some Text Here Some Text Here Some </strong>  <span id="dcountdown"></span> <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" role="button" class="mybutton">Apply Now</a>
      </div>
      <div id="dclose">close me!</div>
    </div>
<script src="https://lizatom.com/wp-content/themes/lizatom2015/banner/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://lizatom.com/wp-content/themes/lizatom2015/banner/jquery.plugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank You I did, but I have encountered another problem on mobile view I am getting some white space on the right side, please help me fix that. I have updated my question with a new screenshot

Comment: `    @media only screen and (max-width: 700px)
    {
        .dcontent strong{
            font-size: 1em; 
            width: 80vw;
            white-space: normal;
       
        }
`